# Problems when processing bytes in perl

Tags: string, perl, binary, byte, bit

I am working on a script that will encrypt a file using RSA. It reads and encrypts 1 byte at a time. Encrypting and decrypting normal .txt files works well, but when encrypting and then decrypting binary files (e.g. .gif) they come out corrupted.

This is done by the encryptFile and decryptFile sub.
I am using the [`IO::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html) module to open files and add [`binmode(":raw")`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) so that when a byte is read it is interpreted as a byte and not text, so this can't be the problem.

When encrypting the bytes I first use my `bytesToBigint()` sub to translate the byte into an integer. Then I use my `rsa::encrypt()` sub to encrypt the integer. Now the encrypted integer will be much larger than 1 byte so I have to represent it in multiple bytes.

I do this in the sub `bigintToBytes()` which basically splits an integer into multiple bytes and stores them in a string. The string is returned and then written to the file.

For example: if `bigintToBytes(16739)` is called then the string `'Ac'` is returned because

- Starting with `16739` (dec)
- → `0100000101100011` (binary)
- → `01000001|01100011`
- → `65|99` (dec)
- and `chr(65) = 'A'` and `chr(99) = 'c'` → `'Ac'`.

This sub may be the cause, but why? is it because I am storing bytes in a string? When calling the `read($buf, $bufsize)` sub on open files, using the `IO::File` module, it also stores bytes in a string, which works.

I would be really thankfull if you point out what I am missing.

Here is the bigintToBytes sub

```
sub bigintToBytes {
    use bignum;
    use bytes;

    my $bigint = shift;
    my $bits_in_int = length_in_bytes($bigint)*8;

    my $bytes = ''; 

    my $new_byte = 0;
    my $count = 0;
    while ($bits_in_int > 0){
        # add first bit in bigint to the new byte
        $new_byte = ($new_byte << 1)|($bigint >> ($bits_in_int-1));

        # remove the first bit in bigint
        $bigint = $bigint & (2**($bits_in_int)-1);
        $bits_in_int--;
        $count++;

        if ($count == 8){
            $bytes = $bytes.chr($new_byte);
            $new_byte = 0;
            $count = 0;
        }
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

I have also added [`use bytes;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bytes.html) to the encryptFile and decryptFile subs if it matter.

I don't feel it is necessary for me to post the bytesToBigint, encryptFile and decryptFile subs, because bytesToBigint basically does the reverse and encryptFile and decryptFile just read the bytes and process them using these function.

Edit:
Here is the code snippet in encryptFile sub. This is where bytesToBigint and encryptFile are used and written to the file.

```
my $bufsize = 1;
my $buf = '';
while ( $file->read($buf, $bufsize)){
    my $msg = myMath::bytesToBigint($buf);
    my $enc_msg = rsa::encrypt($n, $enc_key, $msg);
    my $enc_msg_as_chars = myMath::bigintToBytes($enc_msg);

    #in case the encrypted unit is to small
    while (length($enc_msg_as_chars) < $min_bytes){
        $enc_msg_as_chars = chr(0).$enc_msg_as_chars;
    }

    $newFile->print($enc_msg_as_chars);
}
```

Comment: _" I first use my bytesToBigint() sub to translate the byte into an integer"_ -- why?

Comment: (Get rid of `use bytes;`, that will harm not help)

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is. Are you saying `bigintToBytes` returns an incorrect result? If so, tell us what input you passed to it, what was returned and what should it have returned. (`sprintf('%v02X', $var)` will help you make those variable readable.)

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't return a string with the real bytes. It seems that when bytes are added to the string using chr() they are formatted and don't contain the original information anymore

Comment: Then tell us what input you passed to it, what was returned and what should it have returned.

Comment: For one thing, `bigintToBytes(16739)` shouldn't return `"Ac"`, it should return `"\0\0\0\0\0\0Ac"`. There are likely to be many zero bytes in a graphics file, and if you are removing all leading zeroes from every 64-bit integer then the end result will be nothing like the original. I don't see why you're doing this in eight-byte chunks anyway - you have no way of knowing where to truncate the final block of eight bytes to match the original. By the way, do you mean the [`Crypt::RSA`](https://metacpan.org/module/Crypt::RSA) module?

Comment: if a file uses 64 bit integers i would still read 1 byte at a time (if $bufsize is 1) and encrypt them, and after decrypting them they would be in their place. No I the rsa module I use is my own.

Comment: So the bigintToBytes sub appears to be working, it might be what happens after. I added the part where it is being used and the bytes are written to the new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in bigintToBytes is that it returns an empty string when input integer is zero. So I added

```
if($x == 0){
    return chr(0);
}
```

and the problem is solved!